# Automatically draw ellipsoids around groups of select points

Tags: plotting, graphics

Suppose you have a `ListPlot`, and there are certain points you wish to emphasize belong to particular group. I would like to make a function that automatically draws an ellipsoid around a select group of points. Below I am including an example image of the end goal. Thoughts?
[image: Goal]

### Update 1

So using @Szabolcs answer, I got the following:

```
Legended[Graphics[{{{Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
     Scale[BoundingRegion[redPoints, "FastStadium", 
       WorkingPrecision -> 10], 1.1]}, {PointSize[Medium], 
     Point[redPoints]}}, {{Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[Black], 
     FaceForm[Blue], 
     Scale[BoundingRegion[brainPoints, "FastStadium", 
       WorkingPrecision -> 10], 1.1]}, {PointSize[Medium], 
     Point[bluePoints]}}, {PointSize[Medium], Point[otherPoints]}}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.1}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue, White}, {"Red Region", "Blue Region", 
   "Other"}]]
```

[image]

However, I am unable to add Callouts.... thoughts? Also, how to make the Stadium a bit fatter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've never used this function before, but [`BoundingRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html) seems to be able to do the bulk of the work.

For example,

```
pts = {#1, #1 + #2} & @@@ RandomReal[1, {15, 2}];

Graphics[{
  {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[LightBlue], 
   Scale[BoundingRegion[pts, "FastStadium"], 1.1]},
  Point[pts]
  }]
```

[image]

There's also `"FastEllipse"`, but for some reason it gives less useful looking results.

Comment: thanks. this is quite useful. But does it work also on Mathematica 10? I guess not...

Comment: @Szabolcs this is useful as Luigi stated. However, what is the best way to integrate this into `ListPlot`? The reason is to also integrate `Callout` and have axes, etc

Comment: @Szabolcs ok, so I have started reading the documentation regarding Bounding Regions and what not and will continue doing so. From my understanding ListPlot is just a fancy function that uses a ton of Graphics, but doesn't require the user to do so. So what would be easier: rebuilding ListPlot from the directives with your above code, or adding this BoundingRegions to ListPlot?

Comment: @Szabolcs also I am confused as `BoundingRegion` is not listed as a primitive or directive that can be used in `Graphics`

Comment: @Szabolcs also why do you use `Scale`?

Comment: @SumNeuron 1. I would use `Show[ Graphics[ellipse], ListPlot[ ... ] ]`.  2. See what `BoundingRegion` returns. Not all regions are graphics primitives, but these happen to be (although they're newly introduced ones). 3. I use `Scale` because otherwise some points fall on the boundary.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am adding a generalizable function... thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Following @Szabolc's example, I generalized it for others to use. Does anyone know how to allow one to directly pass `ListPlot` options into this function? Alternatively, one could redefine the function to just take the `ListPlot` object. For completeness I am adding this ListPlot accepting form below.

```
points = {#1, #1 + #2} & @@@ RandomReal[1, {15, 2}];
group1 = points[[1 ;; 5]];
group2 = points[[10 ;; 15]];

Options[ListPlotGroups] = {"FatFactor" -> 1, "Color" -> "Pastel"};
ListPlotGroups[points_, groups_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {numGroups, fatFactor, stadiums, colorIndexes, colors},
  numGroups = Length@groups;
  fatFactor = OptionValue["FatFactor"];
  stadiums = 
   Table[BoundingRegion[groups[[i]], "FastStadium"], {i, numGroups}];
  (stadiums[[#]][[-1]] = stadiums[[#]][[-1]] fatFactor) & /@ 
   Range[numGroups];

  colorIndexes = 
   Riffle[Range[0, 1, 1/numGroups], 
     Reverse[Range[0, 1, 1/numGroups]]][[1 ;; 
      Length@Range[0, 1, 1/numGroups]]];
  colors = 
   Table[ColorData[OptionValue["Color"]][colorIndexes[[i]]], {i, 
     numGroups}];
  Show[ListPlot[points], 
   Graphics[
    Table[{Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[colors[[i]]], 
      stadiums[[i]]}, {i, numGroups}]]]
  ]


ListPlotGroups[points, {group1, group2}, "FatFactor" -> 1]
```

[image]

```
ListPlotGroups[points, {group1, group2}, "FatFactor" -> .5]
```

[image]

This version takes a `ListPlot` and allows for you specify a "FatFactor" for each group.

```
  Options[AddStadiums] = {"FatFactor" -> 1, "Color" -> "Pastel"};
  AddStadiums[listPlot_, groups_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {numGroups, fatFactor, stadiums, colorIndexes, colors},
  numGroups = Length@groups;
  fatFactor = OptionValue["FatFactor"];


  stadiums = 
   Table[BoundingRegion[groups[[i]], "FastStadium"], {i, numGroups}];
  If[Length@OptionValue["FatFactor"] == 0,
   (stadiums[[#]][[-1]] = stadiums[[#]][[-1]] fatFactor) & /@ 
     Range[numGroups];,
   If[Length@OptionValue["FatFactor"] == 1,
     (stadiums[[#]][[-1]] = stadiums[[#]][[-1]] First@fatFactor) & /@ 
       Range[numGroups];,
     (stadiums[[#]][[-1]] = stadiums[[#]][[-1]] fatFactor[[#]]) & /@ 
       Range[numGroups];
     ];
   ];


  colorIndexes = 
   Riffle[Range[0, 1, 1/numGroups], 
     Reverse[Range[0, 1, 1/numGroups]]][[1 ;; 
      Length@Range[0, 1, 1/numGroups]]];
  colors = 
   Table[ColorData[OptionValue["Color"]][colorIndexes[[i]]], {i, 
     numGroups}];
  Show[listPlot, 
   Graphics[
    Table[{Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[colors[[i]]], 
      stadiums[[i]]}, {i, numGroups}]]]
  ]
```

Comment: @Szabolcs how would you improve the syntax of this function?